# Может кто-то объяснить код построчно?

Tags: java, коллекции

Это часть большого кода, в котором есть три четыре класса: OnlineStore, Good, ProductSearchSrvice и класс, где происходят основные действия и, где находиться код ниже), выполняет поиск минимальной цены заданного товара.

```
public double findMinPriceByGoodName(String goodName) {
    double result = 0;
    for (Iterator<OnlineStore> iterator = store.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        OnlineStore onlineStore = iterator.next();
        for (Iterator<Good> iterator1 = onlineStore.getGoods().iterator(); iterator1.hasNext(); ) {
            Good good = iterator1.next();
            if (good.getName().equals(goodName)) {
                if (good.getPrice() < result || result == 0) {
                    result = good.getPrice();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Код ниже это реализация кода выше.

```
List<OnlineStore> stores = new ArrayList<>();
stores.add(MirElecroniki);
stores.add(HIKVISIOB);
stores.add(OLX);

ProductSearchService service = new ProductSearchService(stores);

double minPrice = service.findMinPriceByGoodName("Tuner");
System.out.println("Min price for Tuner" + minPrice);
```

Comment: Для поиска минимального изначально result устанавливают максимальным (Double.MAX_VALUE), а не 0. Тогда не нужна проверка || result == 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public double findMinPriceByGoodName(String goodName) {
    // Минимально возможная цена
    double result = 0;

    // Создаем итератор коллекции store и перебираем его в for, пока есть значения `hasNext()` вернет
    //  false если значений не будет
    for (Iterator<OnlineStore> iterator = store.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        // Вытаскиваем из итератора значение
        OnlineStore onlineStore = iterator.next();

        // Создаем итератор коллекции onlineStore.getGoods() и перебираем его
        for (Iterator<Good> iterator1 = onlineStore.getGoods().iterator(); iterator1.hasNext(); ) {
            // Вытаскиваем значение
            Good good = iterator1.next();

            // Если название товара такое же, которое было передано в функцию (аргумент goodName)
            if (good.getName().equals(goodName)) {
                // Если цена товара меньше текущей минимальной или текущая минимальная равна 0 
                // (думаю, условие с result == 0 нужно чтобы обновить значение в result в случае, 
                // когда первый товар имеет цену выше значения в result по умолчанию -- выше 0,
                // чтобы иметь реальную цену.
                if (good.getPrice() < result || result == 0) {
                    // Обновляем текущую минимальную цену
                    result = good.getPrice();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Возвращаем результат
    return result;
}
```

---

Код можно упростить, если вместо итераторов+for использовать foreach:

```
public double findMinPriceByGoodName(String goodName) {
    double result = 0;

    for (OnlineStore onlineStore : store) {
        for (Good good : onlineStore.getGoods()) {
            if (good.getName().equals(goodName)) {
                if (good.getPrice() < result || result == 0) {
                    result = good.getPrice();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Можно нахождение минимальной цены сделать без условий:

```
public double findMinPriceByGoodName(String goodName) {
    Set<Integer> prices = new HashSet<>();        
    // Или:
    // List<Integer> prices = new ArrayList<>();

    for (OnlineStore onlineStore : store) {
        for (Good good : onlineStore.getGoods()) {
            if (good.getName().equals(goodName)) {
                prices.add(good.getPrice());
            }
        }
    }

    return Collections.min(prices);
}
```